# PropertyGroupDescription not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using `LINQ to SQL` in a `C# WPF` application and I am trying to use `PropertyGroupDescription` to group a `listview` by `LastNames` from a `SQL Server Db`.

My DB LINQ designer mapping for the column looks like this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_LastName", AutoSync=AutoSync.Always, DbType="VarChar(MAX)", IsDbGenerated=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._LastName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._LastName != value))
                {
                    this.OnLastNameChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._LastName = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("LastName");
                    this.OnLastNameChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

The Table Name in the DB is `Contacts`, I thought the linq code for the table is a bit too much to post so I gave the name.

I have a `Observable Collection` of the db table that I am binding the itemsource of the listview to.

```
public ObservableCollection<Namespace.Database.Contact> Contacts
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

Here is how I am trying and failing while using PropertyGroupDescription

```
    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Contacts);
    PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription(this.Contacts.LastName);  //<-- Cant do that
    view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

Since there can be the same last name multiple time, I want to group by it.

I was assuming I could do the above, but cannot:

I have tried:

```
this.Contacts.Where(x => x.LastName!= null).ToString().FirstOrDefault());

this.Contacts.Select(x => x.LastName!= null).ToString()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help or replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Contacts);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("LastName");  
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

instead.

You should use hardcoded property name in PropertyGroupDescription's constructor.

Comment: I knew it would be that easy!!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This method should group and then skip null.

```
    public void test() {

        // This line should work for grouping
        var groupedContacts = Contacts.GroupBy(contact => contact.LastName);
        foreach(var group in groupedContacts){
            string LastName = group.Key;
            if(LastName == null){
                continue;
            }
            foreach(var person in group){
                Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName);
            }
        }

    }
```